# Deleting elements from dictionary values (lists of list)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the key is a tuple and the value is a list of lists. I'd like to modify my dictionary so that the remaining values are only the 2nd, 3rd, 5th elements of the current dictionary, instead of the 7 items that I have now (i.e. 06/20/2015, 00:00:00, 0005192500).

What would be the best way to go about that?

This is what my dictionary looks like.

```
{('A002', 'R051', '02-00-00', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [['NQR456',
                                                  'BMT',
                                                  '06/20/2015',
                                                  '00:00:00',
                                                  'REGULAR',
                                                  '0005192500',
                                                  '0001756572                                     '],
                                                 ['NQR456',
                                                  'BMT',
                                                  '06/20/2015',
                                                  '04:00:00',
                                                  'REGULAR',
                                                  '0005192550',
                                                  '0001756580       

                                                  ']],

('A002', 'R051', '02-00-01', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [['NQR456',
                                              'BMT',
                                              '06/20/2015',
                                              '00:00:00',
                                              'REGULAR',
                                              '0004801812',
                                              '0001047813                                     '],
                                             ['NQR456',
                                              'BMT',
                                              '06/20/2015',
                                              '04:00:00',
                                              'REGULAR',
                                              '0004801850',
                                              '0001047821]]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution:

```
newDict = {k : map(lambda x: [x[2], x[3], x[5]], v) for k, v in dict.items() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
for key in d:
    d[key] = [[l[2], l[3], l[5]] for l in d[key]]
```